# google sheets - replace the second letter in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way I can replace the 2nd character in a cell with an asterisk(`*`)?

Something like this:

```
  var name = publicWinners.getRange(i, 1); 
  name.setValue( → 2nd character = "*" ← );
```

I want to create a list of winners in a contest that can be posted publicly with the winners' personal information partially hidden.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) :

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
const str = "John Doe";
const output = str.replace(/(.{1})./,"$1*");
console.info(output);
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

- `.` - Any character
- `(.{1})` - Any character repeated 1 time. `{1}` may be removed, but used to  quantify previous characters, if you want to  replace the third or fourth character. Capture group`$1`
- `.` - Final character to   replace with `*`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods to manipulate the string.

```
/**
 * Replace a character of a string with a new character at the specified position.
 * @param {string} word - The word to modify.
 * @param {number} index - The character index to modify. Starts from zero.
 * @param {string} newChar - The new character that will overwrite the existing character.
 * @returns {string}
 */
function replaceCharAt(word, index, newChar) {
  return word.split('').map(function(char, charIndex) {
    if (charIndex == index) {
      return newChar;
    }
    return char;
  }).join('');
}
```

A simple test you can run:

```js
var originals = [
  'Sangmyeong',
  'Jaedong',
  'Sangjin',
  'Gueho'
];

originals.forEach(original => console.log(replaceCharAt(original, 1, '*'))); // [S*ngmyeong, J*edong, S*ngjin, G*eho]

function replaceCharAt(word, index, newChar) {
  return word.split('').map(function(char, charIndex) {
    if (charIndex == index) {
      return newChar;
    }
    return char;
  }).join('');
}
```